# Finding maximum of $A=\frac a{2+bc}+\frac b{2+ca}+\frac c{2+ab}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=2$. Find maximum of $$A=\frac{a}{2+bc}+\frac{b}{2+ca}+\frac{c}{2+ab}.$$

I see $\max A=1$ and it occurs when $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$ and its permutation. So I will prove this inequality:$$\frac{a}{2+bc}\le \frac{a}{a+b+c} \quad \text{or} \quad 2+bc\ge a+b+c.$$

It is true because
$$2(2+2bc)=(1+1)(a^2+(b+c)^2)\ge (a+b+c)^2.$$
Is it right? And I want a new method.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the inequality, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @Carl Mummert I think in this question there is context and other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $2(2+2bc)=(1+1)(a^2+(b+c)^2)\ge (a+b+c)^2$, but it doesn't prove your inequality because $2 \le a+b+c$ is not proved. Actually, it is not true. Try $a=b=c=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Instead, $2+bc\ge a+b+c$ is equivalent to$$2-b-c+bc\ge a$$or$$(2-b-c+bc)^2\ge a^2$$or$$b^2 c^2 - 2 b^2 c + 2b^2 - 2 b c^2 + 6 bc - 4 b + 2c^2 - 4 c +2
\ge0$$or$$(b-1)^2(c-1)^2+(b+c-1)^2\ge0$$which is obvious.

Comment: Oh tks $2(2+2bc)=4+4bc\le 4+4bc+b^2c^2=(2+2bc)^2$ now it is true :).